# How can I extract part of a PChar into a string?

Tags: string, delphi, optimization, pchar

During profiling I came across a function that was taking quite a bit of time, but essentially boiled down to this very simple piece of code:

```
function GetSubstring(AInput: PChar; AStart, ASubstringLength: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := Copy(AInput, AStart, ASubstringLength);
end;
```

This function returns the expected sub-string, but it doesn't scale very well for longer inputs. I looked at the assembler code in CPU view, and from what I can tell (I'm not normally working at the assembler level), it seems that `AInput` is implicitly converted into a string before calling `Copy`.

But since at this point the length of the string/character array is unknown, the conversion code has to walk the length of the `PChar` until it finds the null terminator. This would explain the terrible scaling for longer inputs.

However, since the caller passes in the length of the `PChar`, I initially thought could just convert the method to use `SetString` instead.

```
function GetSubstring(AInput: PChar; AStart, ASubstringLength: Integer): string;
begin
  SetString(Result, AInput + AStart - 1, ASubstringLength);
end;
```

In addition to `SetString` working zero-based (not one-based as Copy), there seem to be a number of other little things `Copy` does in terms of validating its inputs, not all of which are documented (e.g. any start value less than 1 is changed to 1). So the naïve implementation above doesn't always work as the original one.

My goal is to replicate the `Copy` routine as much as possible, as this function is part of a library and has been used extensively by my colleagues.

I'm wondering whether the following implementation accomplishes that, or whether I need to be aware of any other caveats of `Copy`. NB: `FLength` is the actual length of `AInput` that comes from another part in the module this function is part of. I removed that other part for this example.

```
function GetSubstring(AInput: PChar; AStart, ASubstringLength: Integer): string;
begin
  if (AInput = nil) then begin
    Result := '';
  end else begin
    if (AStart < 1) then begin
      AStart := 0;
    end else begin
      AStart := AStart - 1;
    end;
    if (ASubstringLength + AStart > FLength) then begin
      ASubstringLength := FLength - AStart;
    end;
    SetString(Result, AInput + AStart, ASubstringLength);
  end;
end;
```

I'm using Delphi 2006, but I assume this isn't much different in other versions of the product (at least the non-Unicode ones).

Comment: You could try to inline `GetSubString()` as well.

Comment: "In addition to SetString working zero-based (not one-based as Copy)" - `SetString()` is not indexed, period. It operates on a starting pointer, not an index. `Copy()` has a 1-based index parameter, and thus the original `GetSubstring()` also had a 1-based `AStart`.  Your initial modified `GetSubstring()` was calculating the wrong pointer. It needed to use `-1` instead of `+1` to preserve the same semantics as `Copy()` (not counting the corner cases): `SetString(Result, Ainput + (AStart - 1), ASubstringLength);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right. I over-simplified the differences between `Copy` and `SetString`. Also, since I didn't have access to my work machine, I had to reproduce the code from memory, which lead to the +1 instead of -1 and `SetString` function/procedure mix-up. Fixed those now.

Comment: @LURD Interestingly enough, after inlining the method it took about twice as long the non-inlined version. Not sure why that is and whether it has to do with the way I measured it; micro-benchmarking is fraught with problems. But not scanning the string in its entirety and copying it every time was performance-boost enough anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's consider the corner cases. I think they are:

1. `AInput` invalid.
2. `AStart < 1`.
3. `AStart > FLength`.
4. `ASubstringLength < 0`.
5. `ASubstringLength + (AStart-1) > FLength`.

We can ignore case 1 in my opinion. The onus should be on the caller to provide a valid `PChar`. Indeed your check that `AInput <> nil` is already a step too far in my view because `nil` is not a valid `PChar`.

Of the rest you have covered 2 and 5, but not 3 and 4. So if the user supplies a value of `AStart` that is too large, then you will read off the end of the string. Likewise, the user can readily supply a negative `ASubstringLength`. I don't think that you need anyone to write the code to check these cases since you are clearly very competent.

Now, if you really care about every last drop of performance, you should not be checking for any of these case. Demand that the user passes valid parameters. In debug mode, with `{$IFOPF D+}` or `Assert` you might check inputs. Of course, if these arguments come from external sources, then they should be validated.

On the other hand, the biggest performance hit the original code suffers is the needless scanning of the entire string, and the copying to an intermediate heap allocated string. Once you've removed those, as you have, then the opportunity for further performance gains is much reduced.

Comment: Actually, the code *IS* using the `System.SetString()` function: `procedure SetString(var s: string; buffer: PChar; len: Integer);` Why do you think it is not?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting `PChar` to `string` you should try to copy the memory from address `AInput + (AStart * SizeOf(PChar))` with a length of `ASubstringLength * SizeOf(PChar)` to `@Result` as it's  much easier to handle `Result` as a pointer.

`Move` procedure could do this.

Comment: SetString does precisely that doesn't it

Comment: My fault. I confused `SetString` with `UniqueString`.

Comment: I guess that SetString checks for null-terminators so that is a difference. But my point is the SetString doesn't create any temp strings and won't run over the whole buffer.

Comment: @David, `SetString` does not check for null terminators. It merely allocates a string and calls `Move`.

Comment: @Rob Thanks. I was just guessing.